# Why does FFMPEG work with 1080p but doesn't work with 720p size… (code included)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I've uploaded my fully compiled code with its Makefile here:

https://pastebin.com/xtCTj06F

If I set 1280x720 I get the segmentation fault:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fdf4d25a600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fdf4d25a600] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fdf4d25a600] 264 - core 148 r2748 97eaef2 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=12 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=12 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=3400 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '1.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 3400 kb/s, 20 tbn
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
sws_scale BEGIN
./MakeVideo.sh: line 2: 26422 Segmentation fault: 11  ./MakeVideo 1.mp4
```

There's some problem with this line:

```
std::cout << "sws_scale BEGIN\n";
sws_scale( sws_context, ( const uint8_t * const * ) &rgb, inLinesize, 0, frame->height, frame->data, frame->linesize );
std::cout << "sws_scale END\n";
```

but if I set the size of a video to 1920x1080 or to 320x240 - all works fine.

Is that some sort of a magick?? Or a bug?

OS X 10.12.3
ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda

Answer (score 1):

Your code has numerous issues. For instance

```
void ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb( AVFrame *frame ) {
// frame pointer may be NULL, but is later used without check

uint8_t *rgb = (uint8_t *) malloc( 3 * sizeof( uint8_t ) * frame->width * frame->height );
// malloc may return NULL, but rgb is later used without check
// also rgb is never freed so memory leaks

sws_context = sws_getCachedContext(...
// sws_getCachedContext may return NULL, but sws_context is later used without check
```

Comment: Well maybe. That's just for the test. But it's not solve the problem. The problem still repeats. I've just checked sws_context - it's never equals to NULL.

Comment: Do you have an actual stack trace from the crash? You may also want to build libav with debug information so you can inspect whatever happens inside of sws_scale() call.

Comment: do I need to rebuild the whole ffmpeg library with --enable-debug? Where to find logs from libav after a crash? Should I simply use gdb and compile my crashing cpp-file with "-Wall -g" and read the gdb-output?

Comment: You can try to debug your application first as it is to inspect the crash call stack, and if it doesn't help then go deeper and rebuild libav with debug information. I don't think there are any kind of logs from libav, but there might be a core dump somewhere if your system if it is configured to produce them. You should compile it with -g3. Turning on warnings including -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic (and fixing them) is a good idea. Also using gdb from command line is contrproductive, installing some IDE would save you a lot of time.